# How to choose a best merging scale?

Tags: physics

I want to do merging, using CKKW-L method ( or other method...) , but I am not familiar with it. I get problem in how to choose a best merging scale, since in the Pythia8 example, the CKKW-L merging scale is already fixed ( they choose t_{ms}=30 ).  I think maybe for different process, the merging scale is different. So is there any conditions to choose a best merging scale?

For example, should I pick some merging scales and output some jet information then choose which one is best?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think its depend on your process. So, you need to see if you are not restricting your phase-space much. I don't have much idea but I found two interesting links about this may be it will help you. They are

1. http://home.thep.lu.se/~prestel/Talks/talk011112.pdf
2. http://home.thep.lu.se/Pythia/pythia82html/CKKWLMerging.html

Comment: Thanks very much and sorry for late reply. I talked to some one who works for these algorithms. He said they think a independent merging scale is physical, so of course when using the algorithms, we don't need to consider the merging scale. Just as you said, whatever but not restricting phase space too much.